# Rutas de perfiles de usuarios

Tags: angular

Tengo usuarios en una base de datos por lo cual quiero mostrar los perfiles de cada usuario de tal manera

http://miweb/usuarios/nickusuario

como podría hacerlo en el app.routing?

Comment: Deberías poner el código de tu router hasta ahora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es posible agregando un solo componente que haga match a diferentes rutas:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  //:username es una variable que sera capturada.
  { path: 'perfil/:username', component: PerfilComponent },
  { path: '**', component: NavegacionComponent }
];
```

Lo capturas de esta manera en tu `perfil.component.ts`

```
 constructor(
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    public location: Location

  ) { 
    //Aqui obtienes el parametro de la ruta. 
    this.usuario = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('username')
    //Despues de esta linea buscas en tu BD por username
  }
```

`ActivatedRoute` te permite obtener los parametros que has definido en el route.

Para la navegacion puedes usar `[routerLink]='["tu", "ruta"]'` de esta manera:

```
<a [routerLink]='["perfil","sutanito"]'>Ver perfil de sutanito</a> <br>
<a [routerLink]='["perfil","fulanito"]'>Ver perfil de fulanito</a> <br>
<a [routerLink]='["perfil","menganito"]'>Ver perfil de menganito</a> <br>
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vvumrt).